# No desktop recording application works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, free-software

I tried with Simple Screen Recorder, kazam, and others, but it doesn't work. In the recording, the background is completely dark and the only thing you can see is the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `recordmydesktop` and it worked for me. I didn't try any other.